# Head first design pattern bug

Tags: php

I am studying Head First - design patterns and translating the exercises to PHP.

I dont get any errors but there is a bug that I cannot figure out.

Edit ( Code ):

```
abstract class Cat 
{
    public $meowBehaviour, $eatBehaviour;
    function __construct(MeowBehaviour $meowBehaviour, EatBehaviour $eatBehaviour)
    {
        $this->meowBehaviour = $meowBehaviour;
        $this->eatBehaviour = $eatBehaviour;
    }
    public abstract function sits();
    public function performMeowBehaviour()
    {
        $this->meowBehaviour->meow();
    }
    public function performEatBehaviour()
    {
        $this->eatBehaviour->eat();
    }
}



interface EatBehaviour {
    public function eat();
}

class EatCatFood implements EatBehaviour {
    public function eat()
    {
        echo "I eat cat food. <br />";
    }
}

class EatGazzelle implements EatBehaviour {
    public function eat()
    {
        echo "I hunt and eat gazzelle. <br />";
    }
}

interface MeowBehaviour {
    public function meow();

}

class Meow implements MeowBehaviour {
    public function meow()
    {
        echo "meow <br />";
    }
}

class Roar implements MeowBehaviour {
    public function meow()
    {
        echo "ROAR! <br />";
    }
}

class HouseCat extends Cat
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new Meow, new EatCatFood);
    }
    public function sits()
    {
        echo "if I fits I sits";
    }
}

class CatSimulator {
    public $cat;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cat = new HouseCat;
        $this->cat->performMeowBehaviour();
        $this->cat->performEatBehaviour();
    }
}

$c = new CatSimulator;
```

the output from CatSimulator is

```
meow 
meow 
I eat cat food.
```

I cannot figure out why 'meow' is repeated.

Comment: Include your complete, properly-formatted code here, please.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP function names are case-insensitive. So here:

```
class Meow implements MeowBehaviour {
    public function meow()
    {
        echo "meow <br />";
    }
}
```

... `meow()` is treated as a constructor (PHP 4.x style) - and gets called on `$this->cat = new HouseCat;` line, echoing the first `'meow'`.

You can rename the class, of course, but there's another alternative: add explicit constructor in that class, as here:

```
class Meow implements MeowBehaviour {
    public function __construct() {}
    public function meow()
    {
        echo "meow <br />";
    }
}
```

Now `meow` method will be called only once.

It's important that `__construct()` precedes `meow()`, otherwise E_STRICT error will be raised. You can read more about it [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_php4_constructors).